# Why my textboxes not showing without maximizing GUI in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

I am trying to create small GUI with couple of textboxes. Shortest code is here:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MortgageCalculator implements ActionListener {

    JTextField loanAmount, loanTerm;
    JFrame jf;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mygui mg = new mygui();
        mg.initUIPanel();
    }

    public void initUIPanel() {
        jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("my gui");
        jf.setLocation(300, 400);
        jf.setSize(400, 500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setResizable(false);

        jf.show();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        loanAmount = new JTextField(15);
        loanAmount.setBounds(170, 20, 125, 20);

        loanTerm = new JTextField(15);
        loanTerm.setBounds(170, 60, 125, 20);

        panel.add(loanAmount);
        panel.add(loanTerm);

        jf.add(panel, "Center");
    }
}
```

The problem is it displays only the frame but not the txtboxes. I can see the boxes only after maximizing the frame once. If minimize it again, then still I can see them, but not at first. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Where are you adding your panels to `JFrame`? Show us the whole necessary code please.

Comment: Call `setVisible( true )` after you added everything

Comment: i have changed the coding.( i mean added more). thanks

Comment: Apply @Robin's comment; use a layout, not `setBounds`.

Comment: Thanks Friends. It worked. I added setVisible(true)for frame at last again. And it worked. I am really very grateful for you guys help. Thanks Robin. Thanks trashgod (for editing my lines as well).

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of this, so JPanel will use default FlowLayout layout manager

```
panel.setLayout(null);
```

You can read more here -> [layouts managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: This is a valuable comment, but it is not an answer.

Comment: Tried. But It messed a lot. The whole structure is messed up.